# update_without_password causes devise to lose password validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Assume my current passwort is 1234 and it has to be at least 4 characters long.

I have 3 input fields in a form:

```
new password
new password confirmation
current password
```

when I use `update_with_password` and the input

```
new password: 5678
new password confirmation: 5678
current paswword: 1234
```

It updates successfully

If for instance I use

```
new password: 12
new password confirmation: 23
current password: 1234
```

I get multiple devise errors: password too short, passwords don't match etc.

when I use `update_without_password` I expect I only need to remove the `current password field` and everything would stay the same.

Instead if I do that and give the input:

```
new password: 12
new password confirmation: 34
```

I get the message `account updated successfully` and **the user record is not updated**

this is my controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def edit
  @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")
end
  def update
    if params[:image_file_path]
      ff = File.open("public/"+params[:image_file_path])
      resource.image = ff
      resource.save!
    end
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = resource.update_without_password(account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      @images = Dir.glob("public/assets/images/users/#{current_user.id}/med/*")
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end


  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :telephone, :image, :address, :birthday)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :telephone, :image, :image_file_path, :address, :birthday)
  end

  protected 

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path
  end

end
```

this is my view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {method: :put }) do |f| %> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password, "Change Password", class: 'control-label' %> 
        <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "New Password Confirmation", class: 'control-label' %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
     </div>
     <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success'  %>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable:update_without_password:

> Updates record attributes without asking for the current password. **Never allows a change to the current password.** If you are using this method, you should probably override this method to protect other attributes you would not like to be updated without a password.

It likely silently ignores the password and password_confirmation parameters in your request.